# Python notation or operation "**"

Tags: python

I saw the following code:

```
def __init__(self, fn, **kw):
     [setattr(self,k,v) for (k,v) in kw.items()]
     ......
```

What does the input argument `**kw` mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kw` is bound to a `dict` mapping [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) names to their values.

Try calling

```
def return_kwargs(**kw):
    return kw
```

as `return_kwargs(foo=1, bar="2", baz="hamspamspam")`.

Comment: So. Suppose the class's name is Foo. Then I can create it as: F=(Foo, a, b, c, d, e). Then kw == {b:c, d:e}???

Comment: @YanZhu: no, because you (a) that doesn't create a `Foo` and (b) if you meant `Foo(a, b, c, d, e)`, that doesn't pass keyword arguments but the values `a` through `e`. Read the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a `dict kw = {'a':1,'b':2}`, then calling `myfunction(**kw)` is equivalent to calling `myfunction(a=1,b=2)`.

Comment: This is the opposite of using `**kw` in the function declaration. The similarity is no accident, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This particular construction means what all keyword arguments for the constructor will end up as object attributes.

```
foo = Foo( func, bar = 1, baz = "aa" )
```

this would create an object with attribute "bar" set to 1 and "baz" to "aa"

Comment: You're right but he's only asking about the `**kw` part. The attribute magic is done by `setattr()`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function, `kw` is a dictionary that contains all the keyword=value arguments that you gave to your function:

```
def demo(**kw):
    print kw

demo(a=1, b="hello")
```

Run the above and it will display a dictionary with two keys, a and b. So it works as a way to accept any keyword argument you decide to use when you call the function.

That's what it does. Why would anyone want to do that? Perhaps in a function that calls another function (given as a separate argument), and `**kw` is to hold options for the second function.